# Change div element content after the video finish

Tags: javascript, html, video

I was wondering if this is possible :

1. I have a movie with a Play button.
2. After click, the movie begins to play.
3. When the movie finish, I have a picture which cover my movie div.

Which options to use in my function:

```
<video src="video.com" id="myVideo">
</video>
<div class="images">
   <img scr="some_pic.jpg" />
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
     document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
     const img = document.querySelector("img")
     const video = document.querySelector("video")
       function myHandler(e) {
        // now the video has to hide, and show the img:
          video.style.display = "none:
          img.style.display = "block"
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various options, including replacing the `<video>` tag with an `<image>` tag.

The easiest one I can think of is to have the image on a layer **under** the video, then when the video finishes, you can change layers (put image as the front layer and now video in the back layer).

When image is under the video, it has same **size** and **position** so to end-user it's invisible. 
 This is set through the `<style=>` part where `z-index` is the layer position (higher number puts it above others of a lower number). The `top` and `left` options are the positions of up/down and left/right settings.

You can try using: 
(in the code below, I change their positions (not aligned) so you can see what is happening)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="myVideo" width="550" height="400" controls style=" z-index: 2; top: 50px; left: 100px; position: absolute; );">
  <source src="some_video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>

<div id="myPic" class="images" width="550" height="400" style=" z-index: 1; top: 80px; left: 140px; position: absolute; );">
    <img src="some_pic.jpg" />
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>

document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
const img = document.getElementById('myPic');
const video = document.getElementById('myVideo');

function myHandler(e) 
{
    // now the video has to hide, and show the img: 
    //video.style.display = "none:
    //img.style.display = "block" 
    
    //# swap their layer positioning
    img.style.zIndex = "2"; //# makes top
    video.style.zIndex = "1"; //# makes bottom

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's something else to it other than simply showing an image when the video is not playing, if that's not the case, the `video` tag has a poster attribute:

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```